# Change "POST" type slug in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

As default wordpress came with a default post type with the slug of "post"!

I wanna change this slug to another one without any headache!

I mean, for example, change the slug `post` to `article`.

How can i achieve that ?

**Update**

This is what i want :

```
function _slug(){
 $args = array(
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'article',
    ),
  ); 
  register_post_type('post',$args);
}
add_action('init', '_slug');
```

But, well that doesn't work!

Comment: Check under Settings > Permalinks

Comment: @Jrod that's not correct! i meant change it from base

Comment: The base structure for post permalinks is usually set in the permalinks settings panel.  If this is not the case for your installation do you know whether or not wordpress has been installed inside a folder called post?  Can you provide a link to your project?

Comment: @Jrod actually that's not my case otherwise that's obvious!

Comment: @Jrod i want to rename post type slug

Comment: Can you provide an example of end url you want to see?  ie www.example.com/post/my-post/

Comment: @Jrod i've an archive.php page that i want to load it by going to `www.example.com/article`. and i know that i can have archive pages for custom post types as this : `archive-{post_type_slug}.php`. my goal is to load archive.php when going to example.com/article

Comment: Change the slug to article in the code you used to register the post type and then re-save your Permalinks.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to use a post type args [filter](https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/filter/) on functions.php file (make sure it run after post type registered):

```
$post_type = <POST TYPE NAME> # Define your own as a string
$new_slug = <WANTED SLUG> # Define your own as a string

add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', function($args, $post_type){
  if ( 'post_type' == $post_type )
     $args['rewrite'] = array( 'slug' => $new_slug );

  return $args;

}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Doesn't work in 2023 unfortuantely