# WordPress a static homepage and custom blog page

Tags: php, wordpress

- I installed Wordpress in "`localhost/`" directory.
- I created a file called `home.php` and designed it as a landing page.
- I want to move my default blog posts to the "`localhost/blog/`" directory.
- But I don't want other links to be affected by this. So "`localhost/blog/contact`" is wrong behavior.

But every way I tried caused problems like this.

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/238727/183195
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/245136/183195
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/131667/183195
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60605443/12944128

All of these only work as a "single post" way. So "`localhost/blog/`" does not contain an archive and will not work. Only the "`localhost/blog/post-slug/`" link works.

Is it that difficult to create a blog with an archive page of its own "`slug`" in WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't believe you can do it without some serious htaccess manipulations. The  permalink structure is set up for either including the 2nd level or not, no in between.