# WordPress: Add directory to post slug with function

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks, slug

I want to add a `/news/` before every post slug. Like this:

example.com **/news/** post-slug/

If I add the `/news/` in the permalinks settings, every custom post type is broken after it.

I tried to add the following to every `register_post_type`:

```
    'with_front'        => false,
```

But that doesn't help.

I also tried the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167373/change-post-type-slug-in-wordpress):

```
$post_type = <POST TYPE NAME> # Define your own as a string
$new_slug = <WANTED SLUG> # Define your own as a string

add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', function($args, $post_type){
  if ( 'post_type' == $post_type )
     $args['rewrite'] = array( 'slug' => $new_slug );

  return $args;

}, 10, 2 );
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work either.

Is there any way to add the `/news/` without breaking the other post types?

Here's the current code for my custom post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_custom' );
function cpt_custom() {
    register_post_type( 'custom',
        array(
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'custom' ),
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'public'            => true,
        'has_archive'       => true,
        'show_in_rest'      => true,
        'with_front'        => true,
        )
    );
}
```

In the permalink settings it's set to `/news/%postname%/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. You have to add the `with_front` attribute inside the `rewrite`.

Like this:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'custom', 'with_front' => false ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the custom post-type slug by adding:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'news' ),
```

to your custom post type arguments.
All posts will now have the 'news' permalink without affecting the others.

Comment: Thanks! But I already use the rewrite argument for the custom post types. I want to add the `/news/` part to the built in posts

Comment: Oh i see, yeah if you rewrite the structure for the custom post types first, then change the permalink value within the Wordpress permalinks settings for Post - it should work

Comment: I thought so too, but it doesn't :-(

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of your permalink settings?

Comment: thanks. Ok in your functions, the arguments that register the post types, remove the 'with_front' reference so default is true & also, do you have `has_archive` set to to true?

Comment: did you try setting has_archive ^ ? @Cray

Comment: Hi, yes. But it doesn't help. The CPT already had `has_archive` :-(

Comment: ok thanks, can you provide a copy of the functions.php or to where all the custom post types are created?

Comment: I added the code for the custom post type in my quetion